# Unit testing with third party libraries and Carthage

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, carthage

What is the proper way to use Carthage for dependency management, but also be able to write tests with it for types it pulls in.  For example, (this is hypothetical) if I pull in AlamoFire and let’s say it has a Response protocol and different concrete types conform to the Response protocol.  In my own library, if I were to do

```
   @testable import AlamoFire
```

it would complain that Module ‘AlamoFire’ was not compiled for testing.  Doing some research, I believe it’s because enable testability should be set to NO on release builds, which Carthage uses by default.  Is there a way to use third party types like this in your test target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `import` instead of `@testable import` to access a module's public types.

Also in your test target's Build Phases, add AlamoFire to "Link Binary With Libraries"

Comment: when I do that I get `framework not found LibraryName for architecture x86_64. Is there something else I need to do? Thanks.

Comment: Yes that is already done since I pull in the dependency through Carthage and have a Run Script phase as outlined in the Carthage README.

Comment: Now we're reaching the edges of my Carthage knowledge. Did you list AlamoFire in your `Cartfile.private` file?

Comment: I have a Cartfile and Cartifle.resolved.  Which one is the .private file? Basically in my Cartfile, I have my third party library declared, I pull in that dependency with Carthage, link it, set up the run script build phase. But if I try to use an interface of that type in a test target, I get the module is not built for testing. But if I import it without @testable like you mentioned, then I get the library not found for arch. Does that clear it up?

Comment: `Cartfile.private` is an additional file used to specify dependencies of test targets. See https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/693 for discussion

Comment: to clarify, adding a third party library to both the framework target and test target is "ok"?

Comment: Yes. I don't understand the nuance of why it's necessary, but it is.

Comment: I get the "Use of undeclared identifier" error in every line referencing a public type if I use `import` instead of `@testable import`. Do you know how might it be fixed?