# How to use @testable import for frameworks built via Carthage

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, testing, frameworks, carthage

I've already read answers for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48388957/unit-testing-with-third-party-libraries-and-carthage) but I'm not satisfied.

Is there any possibility to use `@testable` for external libraries e.g. Alamofire, RxRealm (reason why I would like to do that is that, some classes are not open and **in some cases it's not possible to create mock in unit tests without overriding real implementation**).

Answer (score 0):

Carthage doesn't build frameworks for testing. That's actually a good thing.

Library authors give guarantees on how the *public* interface of their software behaves, but have the freedom to change the *private* interface of it as much as necessary.

Instead of trying to subclass the implementation of your third party dependencies types to create test doubles for them, I would recommend to **put a protocol in front of the subset of functionality you need from the library and only interact with the protocol in your production code**.

*If you have a particular case you'd like to test could you please update the question with it? I'd love to see if I can help.*